# use winforms application to detect form fields in a browser

Tags: c#, winforms, browser

I have a requirement to create a windows form control which has to detect username, password and address fields in a browser.. so when i navigate to a page that asks for a username or password, the application asks me if it should fill in the data for me.

How do i get the form fields in a browser?

and how do i fill them in, and then submit?

thanks in advance

Comment: are you using the WebBrowser control or you want to do this in any Browser on the client Computer?

Comment: i want to use this in any browser that is open on the user's machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it makes more sense to write an addin/ActiveX control. That way it may better interact with the browser object model. I guess, the tool must intercept the HTTP request and parse for `<input name="password>` etc.

Otherwise, you will need to write low-level hooks that attach a 'spy' module. This approach is too error-prone and browser- and platform-dependent.

Comment: it's the low level hooks you mention that i am interested in. do you perhaps have some info on that?

Comment: Try reading http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632589%28VS.85%29.aspx. It'll probably leave you with more questions than answers though.
[1] []